# write lists as columns in a txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to write lists as columns in a txt file. I tried to do this like so:

```
lst_h_names=['name_1','namenamename','nam3','4']
lst_h_1_cont=[1,2,3000,4]
lst_h_2_cont=[1,2000,3,4]
lst_scaling_factor=[10,2,3,4]
array_h_names=np.array(lst_h_names)
array_h_1_cont=np.array(lst_h_1_cont)
array_h_2_cont=np.array(lst_h_2_cont)
array_scaling_factor=np.array(lst_scaling_factor)
norm_factors=np.array([array_h_names,array_h_1_cont,array_h_2_cont,array_scaling_factor])
norm_factors=norm_factors.T
print(norm_factors)
norm_factors_path='all_factors_np.txt'
with open(norm_factors_path,'w') as fil:
    np.savetxt(fil,norm_factors,fmt=['%s','%i','%i','%i'])
```

This raises the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1433                 try:
-> 1434                     v = format % tuple(row) + newline
   1435                 except TypeError:

TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not numpy.str_

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-5b3aeaae6c1a> in <module>
     20 norm_factors_path='all_factors_np.txt'
     21 with open(norm_factors_path,'w') as fil:
---> 22         np.savetxt(fil,norm_factors,fmt=['%s','%i','%i','%i'])

<__array_function__ internals> in savetxt(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1436                     raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
   1437                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
-> 1438                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))
   1439                 fh.write(v)
   1440 

TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U21') and format specifier ('%s %i %i %i')
```

I understand why this doesn't work, but I don't quite know how to do it differently

Comment: The error is telling you that you're using `%i` in a format string, but the data it's supposed to display is a string type - not an integer. You need to adjust your format string to use `%s` where appropriate.

Comment: @Todd: the use of np.savetxt is inappropriate here I would say - it's not that the OP's string formatting is wrong

Comment: @MrFuppes the format string definitely is causing the specific error. Whether they could be using another call here that's more appropriate is secondary.

Comment: @very_much_beginner: welcome to SO btw.!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write an array with string dtype:

```
In [11]: norm_factors                                                                          
Out[11]: 
array([['name_1', '1', '1', '10'],
       ['namenamename', '2', '2000', '2'],
       ['nam3', '3000', '3', '3'],
       ['4', '4', '4', '4']], dtype='<U21')
```

As others point out, only '%s' can format that.

`savetxt` iterates on rows of the array, and formats and writes it

```
 fmt%tuple(row)
```

As the error notes, it has converted your `fmt` into ''%s %i %i %i'.  So it's try to:

```
 '%s %i %i %i'%tuple(norm_factors[0])
```

An alternative to the '%s %s %s %s' is to make an `object` dtype array:

```
In [26]: norm_factors=np.array([array_h_names,array_h_1_cont,array_h_2_cont,array_scaling_factor], dtype=object).T                                                                   
In [27]: norm_factors                                                                          
Out[27]: 
array([['name_1', 1, 1, 10],
       ['namenamename', 2, 2000, 2],
       ['nam3', 3000, 3, 3],
       ['4', 4, 4, 4]], dtype=object)
In [28]: fmt = '%s %i %i %i'                                                                   
In [29]: fmt%tuple(norm_factors[0])                                                            
Out[29]: 'name_1 1 1 10'
```

You could also make a structured array, but the object dtype is simpler.

And the `zip` lists approach is just as good.

Comment: I like that you address the string formatting error in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) which is convenient:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(norm_factors).to_csv('yourfile.txt',header=None, index=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it works:

```
>>> np.savetxt(fil,norm_factors,fmt=['%s','%s','%s','%s'])
```

`%s` can handle both string types and integer types in formatting. But to get more precise formatting, you can refer to the link I have below.

The problem that the error message is telling you is you're trying to represent a string type as a numeric type:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U21') and format specifier
('%s %i %i %i')
```

Here's a reference on string formatting:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

The other answers give some good advice on other aspects of your code.

Comment: Ah yes, you did mention that. @MrFuppes however, it's not immediately jumping out =)

Comment: alright, nevermind ;-) I agree with you that the OP's format string is wrong, but his idea is not that far off, I'd give him that. The problem I see is that np.savetxt would require a structured array as input to do what the OP had in mind (at least as I understand). That seems a bit over-the-top to me, that's why I would discourage using it in this case.

Comment: Your feedback for the OP is definitely good though. @MrFuppes